# How to find VPTR in C++ assembly code?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, code-generation, vptr

```
class Base {
 public:
  Base() {}
  virtual void Get() { }
};

class Derivered : public Base {
 public:
  virtual void Get() { }
};

int main() {
  Base* base = new Derivered();
  base->Get();
  return 0;
}
```

I use gcc 5.4.0 to compile the code, and use `objdump -S a.out` to disassemble binary file. I want to find Base's vptr, but only display an unknown address `0x80487d4`. The max address number is `0x80487b7`, I cann't understand.
command list: `g++ test.cpp -O0; objdump -S a.out`

```
080486fe <_ZN4BaseC1Ev>:
 80486fe:   55                      push   %ebp
 80486ff:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048701:   ba d4 87 04 08          mov    $0x80487d4,%edx
 8048706:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
 8048709:   89 10                   mov    %edx,(%eax)
```

Comment: Make sure optimizations are off.

Comment: Have you read this [article](http://phrack.org/issues/56/8.html) ?

Comment: If you turn optimizations, its easy for the compiler to *Devirtualize* the function call, inline it, and even eliminate it, as in this context,

Comment: Yes, optimizations is closed off.

Comment: Show the output of `objdump -h a.out`

Comment: @RustyX sorry, i cann't find any useful info.

Comment: Which processor?  Assembly language is processor dependent.  Linux can run on an ARM processor (and thus have different assembly language).

Comment: Try `volatile` variables

Answer (score 0):

```
080486fe <_ZN4BaseC1Ev>:
  80486fe:   55                      push   %ebp
  80486ff:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  8048701:   ba d4 87 04 08          mov    $0x80487d4,%edx
  8048706:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
  8048709:   89 10                   mov    %edx,(%eax)
```

Is...

```
push %ebp             ;- save frame pointer
mov %esp, %ebp        ;- mov esp-> ebp -ebp is frame pointer
mov $0x80487d4, %edx  ; load vptr address into edx
mov 0x8(%ebp), %eax   ; ld eax with address of this
mov %edx,(%eax)       ; store vptr in this byte 0
```